# Laravel - How to return json error message on error?

Tags: php, json, laravel, x-editable

I just added x-editable to my current Laravel project. It works perfectly well but I have a problem with **returning the error message**.

When the controller is able to save the request, I get a 'Success!' json message. That's fine. But when I have an error, I do not get the 'Error!' message. As you can see I fire up the error message when $article->save() was not successful.

What am I doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
$article->$input['name'] = $input['value'];

if( $article->save() ){
    // this works
    return response()->json(array('status'=>'success', 'msg'=>'Success!.'), 200);
} 

else{
    // this does not work
    return response()->json(array('status'=>'error', 'msg'=>'Error!'), 500);
}
```

**JavaScript in View:**

```
$(".xeditable").editable({
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.msg);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        // console says, that response.msg is undefinded
        console.log(response.msg);
    }
});
```

Kind regards.

Comment: can you try to print the response?

Comment: You can put this block on a try catch and return error response on catch.

Answer (score 1):

On `error` callback, the passed `response` parameter is jqXHR ([jQuery XMLHttpRequest](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)). In order to access the JSON response, you can access the `responseJSON` property like the code below.

```
$(".xeditable").editable({
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.msg);
    // Must return nothing.
  },
  error: function(response) {
    // The JSON object stored in responseJSON property.
    console.log(response.responseJSON.msg);

    // Must return a string, represent the error message.
    return response.responseJSON.msg;
  }
});
```

As pointed on the X-editable documentation, the `error` callback must return a string that represents the error message.

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with `x-editable` but try to change the response code in case of error from `500` to `200` and then in your javascript

```
$(".xeditable").editable({
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'error') {
            console.log('error: ' + response.msg);
        }
        else {
            // do stuff for successful calls
            console.log('success: ' + response.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('server error: ' + status + ' ' + error);
    }
});
```